How to create new attribute/column in a Table in Power Apps using Plugin?

I want to create dynamic attributes in a table in Power Apps. Using the below code snippet to create Attribute in a custom table. Attribute created successfully, but, I'm getting one error dialogue - How to remove this error dialogue box?

Error Dialogue Screenshot(Click Me)
Using Below Code Snippet(C#) -
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.PluginTelemetry;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace NewPluginAddAttribute002
{
    public class AddDynamicAttributePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Obtain the tracing service
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // Obtain the organization service reference which you will need for web service calls.
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Plugin execution started.");

            try
            {
                if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
                {
                    Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                    string entityLogicalName = entity.LogicalName;

                    tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Entity logical name is {0}", entityLogicalName);

                    // Check if the target entity is new_demotable001
                    if (entityLogicalName != "new_demotable001")
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Target entity is not new_demotable001.");
                        return;
                    }

                    tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Target entity is new_demotable001. Proceeding to add attribute.");

                    // Define the new attribute
                    StringAttributeMetadata newAttribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
                    {
                        SchemaName = "new_dynamicAttribute",
                        DisplayName = new Label("Dynamic Attribute", 1033),
                        RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(AttributeRequiredLevel.None),
                        MaxLength = 100,
                        Format = StringFormat.Text,
                    };

                    // Create the request to add the attribute
                    CreateAttributeRequest createAttributeRequest = new CreateAttributeRequest
                    {
                        EntityName = "new_demotable001",
                        Attribute = newAttribute
                    };

                    // Execute the request outside the plugin transaction
                    ExecuteMultipleRequest executeMultipleRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                    {
                        Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                        {
                            ContinueOnError = false,
                            ReturnResponses = true
                        },
                        Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                    };
                    executeMultipleRequest.Requests.Add(createAttributeRequest);

                    IOrganizationService asyncService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
                    ExecuteMultipleResponse response = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)asyncService.Execute(executeMultipleRequest);

                    if (response.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        foreach (var responseItem in response.Responses)
                        {
                            if (responseItem.Fault != null)
                            {
                                tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Error in response - {0}", responseItem.Fault.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Error occurred while creating the attribute.");
                    }

                    tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Attribute created successfully.");
                }
            }
            catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                tracingService.Trace("AddDynamicAttributePlugin: Plugin execution ended.");
            }
        }
    }
}

Please help me find a way to remove that Error Dialogue or sugget another way to achieve my requiremnt.
Thanks & Regards
